# Swiping between the same fragment type

Tags: android, swipe

I am trying to create swiping animation for one fragment type, FrontCardFragment, such that while that fragment is showing, if swiped left or right, it will display animation and create another FrontCardFragment, but with different attributes .

As of now, when I swipe left or right, I see that the attribute indeed changes, but there is no actual animation. I suspect that I'm not calling the animations correctly -- which are in my `animator` folder -- in addition to something else that I do not know.

Here is what I have

```
public static class FrontCardFragment extends Fragment {

    private static FrontCardFragment clone(FrontCardFragment frontCardFragment){
        FrontCardFragment clone = new FrontCardFragment();
        //copy common values from bundle...
        return clone;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.front_card_fragment, container, false);
        view.setClickable(true);
        view.setFocusable(true);
        setUpGestures(view);
        return view;
    }

    public void setUpGestures(View view){

        final GestureDetector gesture = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                                   float velocityY) {
                final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
                final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
                final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
                try {
                    if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                        return false;
                    if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                        Log.i("INFO", "*************Right to Left");
                        incrementCurrentIndex();
                        getFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.anim_slide_in_right, R.animator.anim_slide_out_right)
                                .replace(R.id.container, FrontCardFragment.clone(FrontCardFragment.this))
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();
                    } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                        Log.i("INFO", "************Left to Right");
                        decrementCurrentIndex();
                        getFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.anim_slide_out_right, R.animator.anim_slide_in_right)
                                .replace(R.id.container, FrontCardFragment.clone(FrontCardFragment.this))
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
            }
        });

        view.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if(currentIndex != -1 && documents.get(currentIndex) != null) {
            ((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.frontText))
                    .setText(documents.get(currentIndex).getString(getArguments().getString("card_type")));
        } else {
            ((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.frontText))
                    .setText("DB is empty for " + getArguments().getString("navigation_item") + " cards");
        }
    }
}
```

and my animations are:

anim_slide_in_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Sliding from right (100) to left (0)-->
    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </objectAnimator>
</set>
```

anim_slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Sliding from left (-100) to right (0)-->
    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </objectAnimator>
</set>
```

anim_slide_out_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Sliding from right (0) to left (-100)-->
    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%" >
    </objectAnimator>
</set>
```

anim_slide_out_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Sliding from left (0) to right (100)-->
    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%" >
    </objectAnimator>
</set>
```

Comment: So nothing happens? Not even the fragment changed?

Comment: @vilpe89 Forgive me for my very late response...it appears that the attributes are actually changed, which to me means that the fragment indeed is being updated, but I don't see the sliding animation for some reason. So, if the current value on the screen is 'foo', when I swipe I see that it updates to 'bar', but no actual animation.